# return a 404 status code and get no contents in response

Tags: c#, .net, api

I throw my custom exception when my StatusCode is 404 the browser get 200 and gets no content but with the other StatusCode things work fine

how to fix this problem and get the 404 in my response not 200

this is my middleware

```
public static class ExceptionHandlingMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseNativeGlobalExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
            {
                errorApp.Run(async context =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        var exception = errorFeature.Error;
                    
                        // Log exception and/or run some other necessary code...

                        var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();

                        if (exception is HttpException httpException)
                        {
                            errorResponse.StatusCode = httpException.StatusCode;
                            errorResponse.Message = httpException.Message;
                        }

                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int) errorResponse.StatusCode;
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(errorResponse.ToJsonString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        throw;
                    }
                });
            });

            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Controller where I throw 404 StatusCode[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgUGs.png)

```
[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            throw new HttpException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not found");
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                })
                .ToArray();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Your postman screenshot shows an Aborted error, which is very different than a completed response which contains HTTP Status Code 404.

Comment: @gunr2171 but when I change the 404 to 500 or 200 everything is going as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the not found method from `ControllerBase` class.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
```

Extend your controller to use base class. It should be like this:

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Ok this solution  work fine but i want to know what is  solution   problem